# Issue with H2 DATEDIFF function using Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

There is a simple entity *Item* with two date type properties:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
protected Long id;

@NotNull
protected String name;

@NotNull
protected Date from;

@NotNull
protected Date to
```

I want to use the propritary function of H2 database **"DATEDIFF"** using Criteria API. So I have below snippet code to do this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Item> criteria = cb.createQuery(Item.class);
Root<Item> i = criteria.from(Item.class);
criteria.select(i).where(
      cb.gt(
            cb.function(
                        "DATEDIFF",
                        Integer.class,
                        cb.literal("DAY"),
                        i.get("from"),
                        i.get("to")
            ),
            1
      )
);
... // other code to handle result
```

When I try to execute query I get this error:

> WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error:
>   90008, SQLState: 90008 ERROR
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid value "1"
>   for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200] at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:590)
>     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getInvalidValueException(DbException.java:280)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.setParameter(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1503)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.setString(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:413)   at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:648)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396)   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
>     at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)  at
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
>     at
>   com.ico.ltd.querying.domain.Restriction.executeQueries(Restriction.java:329)

But if I use JPQL:

```
 select i from Item i where function('DATEDIFF', 'DAY', i.from, i.to) > 1
```

It completes without any issue. Moreover if I switch version of H2 to 1.3.171, Criteria API works fine.
I use the following versions of H2 and Hibernate **1.4.200**, **5.4.8.Final** accordingly.
Could somebody help with this?

Comment: Have you found any solution? If yes could you please post it?

Comment: @bazsoja, Unfortunately I have not found the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a literal for your integer value 1 that you compare to:

```
CriteriaQuery<Item> criteria = cb.createQuery(Item.class);
Root<Item> i = criteria.from(Item.class);
criteria.select(i).where(
      cb.gt(
            cb.function(
                        "DATEDIFF",
                        Integer.class,
                        cb.literal("DAY"),
                        i.get("from"),
                        i.get("to")
            ),
            cb.literal(1)
      )
);
```